# Adjust refresh rate?

Tags: release-juno, display, amd

I'm trying to increase the refresh rate of my monitor on eOS 5.0
As other posts suggested I tried to use xrandr to adjust the refresh rate, from 60Hz to my monitors native 75Hz. According to the system it works, but actually feels more sluggish than 60Hz. The cursor does feel smoother, but everything else in the system does not. Any suggestions?
I'm running with Radeon RX 480 graphics, if that makes a difference.